# Can I integrate WhatsApp video chat capability into my react.js app?

Tags: whatsapp, twilio-api

I wanted to build an react.js e-commerce app that enabled 1:1 video chat capability between buyer and seller, and I wanted (wondered if) to use Whatsapp video chat capability.

Does Whatsapp support such kind of 3rd-party integration? (Like [https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone={phone_no}](https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%7Bphone_no%7D) to send messages. Is there any link to start video chat to a phone number using Whatsapp api)

Comment: Doesn't look like it's supported. At least nothing documented in the [technical requirements page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/reference). But I would suggest checking by reaching out to them over [here](https://www.facebook.com/business/m/whatsapp/business-api).